# JSON response with different results based on conditions - need guidelines

Tags: json, rest

What is the best approach to include or exclude a field in JSON whose value depends on another field. In the below example, phone_number and email fields will have a value or null based on auth_type field.

In the approach A, if the auth_type is phone then email field is not sent in the api response but in approach B, if the auth_type is phone then email field is send with null value. Which approach is good ?

Approach A:

```
{
    id: 123,
    ...
    auth_type: 'Phone',
    phone_number: 123456
}

{
    id: 123,
    ...
    auth_type: 'email',
    email: 'abc@abc.com'
}
```

Approach B:

```
{
    id: 123,
    ...
    auth_type: 'Phone',
    phone_number: 123456,
    email: null
}
{
    id: 123,
    ...
    auth_type: 'email',
    phone_number: null,
    email: 'abc@abc.com'
}
```

Comment: Personally I prefer coding in typescript, So I go about with approach A. unless there is a piece of code `obj.email` explicitly on both type of response I think you can go about with approach A.

Comment: json is about transport. less is better.